# Как задать имя файлу?

Tags: javascript, native

```
function generate_file(data){
    var data=new Blob(["\ufeff", [data]],{type:'plain/text'});
    var file=window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    return file;
}
var data="some string\nanother string";
file=generate_file(data);
window.location.href=file;
```

Как задать имя файлу? Или хотя б расширение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var saveFile = function (data, fileName) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", [data]],{type:'plain/text'});
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};

var data="some string\nanother string";
var fileName = "my-data.json";

saveFile(data, fileName);
```